# Where to put flavor manifests to get them merged with main AndroidManifest file

Tags: android, gradle

I have a gradle project with flavorgroups and flavors. Where to put per flavors AndroidManifest.xml so it gets merged with the main Manifest? Now for example I've put the AndroidManifest.xml into 'amazon' folder. It has few more permissions than the main one. But those two doesn't get merged. It's only Manifest problem. Other resource files like strings and drawables gets merged properly.

My build.gradle file is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.6'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}

defaultConfig {
    ...
}

signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("debug.keystore")
    }

    release {
        ...
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebugBuild true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        packageNameSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix ".debug"
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        jniDebugBuild false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

flavorGroups "version", "market"


productFlavors {
    amazon {
        flavorGroup "market"
        buildConfig "public static final int COMPILATION = 1;"
    }
    google {
        flavorGroup "market"
        buildConfig "public static final int COMPILATION = 0;"
    }
    lite {
        flavorGroup "version"

        packageName = "package.name.lite"
    }
    full {
        flavorGroup "version"

        packageName = "package.name.full"
    }
}

android.sourceSets.amazon {
    res {
        srcDir "amazon"
    }
    manifest {
        srcFile "amazon/AndroidManifest.xml"
    }
}

android.sourceSets.google {
    res {
        srcDir "google"
    }
}

android.sourceSets.full {
    res {
        srcDir "full"
    }
}

android.sourceSets.lite {
    res {
        srcDir "lite"
    }
}
}
```

edit:

It seems that Manifests are merging actually (I didn't notice it because the persmissions were added at the bottom of file). But it works only when one tag is missing in original Manifest file and exist in flavor Manifest. Sometimes i want to override an attribute of existing tag and then it isn't working. Is it gradle issue or I am doing sth wrong?

Comment: I am seeing different results. I am seeing merging of manifest files over different buildtypes. Not sure why that is happening though.

Answer (score 0):

You should have directories for the various flavors. Each flavor can have an AndroidManifest.xml defined in the same place as the default directory (except in its own branch in the tree). You should be able to define just the 'pieces' you want to be different for the flavor.

Comment: what is the android.xml file?